# How to view the MySQL password isnot hashed?

Tags: mysql

I am new in MySQL and I want to see the password in MySQL users table isn't hashed as  "876da97d80181a1088ca9e3050025".

How can i do to see it as i lost the password ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can't.

A hash value is not reversable. It is used to hide the password. At login time you create a hash of the value you inputted and compare that to the stored hash to see if they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot found a hashed password. But if you have root access to the server, you can reconfigure the mysql package and redefine it.

For example if your OS is debian based, this should be something like this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

This will display a prompt asking for a new root password.